# cannot detect collisions in the room model loaded from glb

Tags: three.js, 3d, react-three-fiber, cannon.js

I am creating a first person game.
The room model has only walls and floors.
The model is npx gltfjsx . /public/box2.glb and converted to React code.
It is then loaded using GLTFLoader.

The model I loaded is written in CannonJs Physics but the collision detection does not work.

However, in the floor code I created, the collision detection is working.

What am I missing?
Or is there another way?

sample code
https://codesandbox.io/s/glb-fps-qzrjbj

Comment: Hello, did you happen to find any solution?